# How to plot in this kind of graph in Python or R?

Tags: python, r, matplotlib

I have searched about how to plot the graph by matplotlib or ggplot but I couldn't figure out how to make it.

[image: this is the graph that I wanna make]

from Nature 500(7463):415-421 August 2013.

so I wanna plot in dots and with a mark for median, kind of showing distribution.

million thanks for any help!

Comment: Can you please share the (or sample) data?

Comment: Take a look at function boxplot from library  ggplot2 in R

Comment: [Here is the article](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3776390). It has supplementary data attached as XLS files, which is our starting point.

Comment: may be  need some sample data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This question is really about how to research the literature. So let's do that.

[Here's the article in PubMed](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/23945592). It's also freely-available [at PubMed Central](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3776390). There, we find supplementary data files in XLS format. The file with data closest to what we need [is this XLS file](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3776390/bin/NIHMS54099-supplement-2.xls). Unfortunately, exploration reveals that it contains only 8 distinct tissue types, whereas Figure 1 contains 30. So we cannot reproduce that figure from the data. This is not uncommon in science.

*However*: the figure caption points us to [this article](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3919509), which contains a similar figure. Data is available in [this XLS file](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3919509/bin/NIHMS471461-supplement-3.xls).

I downloaded that file, opened in Excel and saved as the latest XLSX format. Now we can read it into R, assuming the file is in Downloads:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(readxl)
tableS2 <- read_excel("~/Downloads/NIHMS471461-supplement-3.xlsx", 
                      sheet = "Table S2")
```

Now we read the figure caption:

> Each dot corresponds to a tumor-normal pair, with vertical position indicating the total frequency of somatic mutations in the exome. Tumor types are ordered by their median somatic mutation frequency...

In our file, the pairs correspond to `name`, total frequency is `n_coding_mutations` and somatic mutation frequency is `coding_mutation_rate`. So we want to:

- group by `tumor_type`
- calculate the median of `coding_mutation_rate`
- order the values of `n_coding_mutations` within `tumor_type`
- order `tumor_type` by median `coding_mutation_rate`

And then plot the ordered total frequencies versus sample, grouped by the ordered tumor types.

Which might look something like this:

```
tableS2 %>% 
  group_by(tumor_type) %>% 
  mutate(median_n = median(n_coding_mutations)) %>% 
  arrange(tumor_type, coding_mutation_rate) %>% 
  mutate(idx = row_number()) %>% 
  arrange(median_n) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  mutate(tumor_type = factor(tumor_type, 
                             levels = unique(tumor_type))) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(idx, n_coding_mutations)) + 
    geom_point() + 
    facet_grid(~tumor_type,
               switch = "x") + 
    scale_y_log10() + 
    geom_hline(aes(yintercept = median_n), 
               color = "red") + 
    theme_minimal() + 
    theme(strip.text.x = element_text(angle = 90), 
           axis.title.x = element_blank(), 
           axis.text.x = element_blank())
```

Result:

[image]

Which looks pretty close to the original:

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much! Actually what I could not know is how to do this instead of a box and whisker diagram...your explanation's very clear, thank you!

Comment: Please vote and accept the answer if it helped. Personally I think a box or violin plot would be better :) but I can see what they were trying to do.